# Implementing displayed code with provided data set (RStudio)

Tags: r, prediction, google-trends

I have some code for predicting automobile sales, and I need to implement the same code with new data sets that I have found, and I have been unable to do so.

Here's an excerpt of the code:

```
##### Import Google Trends Data
google = read.csv(’googletrends.csv’);
**google$date = as.Date(google$date);** -> error line

##### Sales Data
dat = read.csv("FordSales.csv");
**dat$month = as.Date(dat$month);** -> error line
##### get ready for the forecasting;
dat = rbind(dat, dat[nrow(dat), ]);
dat[nrow(dat), ’month’] = as.Date(’2008-09-01’);
dat[nrow(dat), -1] = rep(NA, ncol(dat)-1);

##### Define Predictors - Time Lags;
dat$s1 = c(NA, dat$sales[1:(nrow(dat)-1)]);
dat$s12 = c(rep(NA, 12), dat$sales[1:(nrow(dat)-12)]);

##### Plot Sales & Google Trends data;
par(mfrow=c(2,1));
plot(sales ~ month, data= dat, lwd=2, type=’l’, main=’Ford Sales’,
ylab=’Sales’, xlab=’Time’);
plot(trends ~ date, data= google, lwd=2, type=’l’, main=’Google Trends: Ford’,
ylab=’Percentage Change’, xlab=’Time’);

##### Merge Sales Data w/ Google Trends Data
google$month = as.Date(paste(substr(google$date, 1, 7), ’01’, sep=’-’))
dat = merge(dat, google);
```

Excerpts from provided data sets: [image] [image]

The error is as follows:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

This error repeats for both the highlighted lines on my code (in bold ** **)

How do I go about it?

Comment: What's the problem with implementing new data? If you wrote code once, write it again.

Comment: while writing the second line of the code its giving me error in charto date(x) character string is not in standard format so how do i change the format for both the datasets one is in week and other is in monthly words

Comment: Then update your question with data you're using (not pictures) and exact code line that gives your error, otherwise (I guess) your question will be closed as "too broad".

Comment: The question has been updated with the error message and the two lines of code where the error takes place have been highlighted now (in bold ** **).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for `as.Date` with `?as.Date`. It has a `format` parameter that lets you specify a string to tell the function what format the date is in, using `strptime`.

In this case, it looks like the second picture is in `%d/%m/%y` (day, month, year with 2 digits), while the first is `%b-%d` (abbreviated month name). I don't know if this will work though on your data without a minimal reproducible example. You might also have a problem that the first data has no year.